# Trouble using @Query with Spring-Boot JPA and Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to spring-boot and have been steadily making progress building up my project but I've come to a point where I need to execute a specific query instead of the ones built by spring.

Here is what my @Query looks like:

```
@Query("select top 1 * from 'table name' where 'column' like 'value' and    message like 'value' order by 'column' desc")
```

Due to it being work-related I had to replace our database specific information but I think you guys should still be able to get the idea of what I'm trying to do. My boss wants this query because, without it formatted like this, we are returned many results and we only want the most recent - thus the top 1 and the order by.

The error I'm seeing is "< operator> or AS expected, got '1'" and, so far, I have yet to find anything on Google.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @NeilStockton - I updated my query to look more like the jpql format `code`@Query(value = "select gl from table gl where gl.column1 like ?1 and gl.column2 = 'stuff' order by gl.column desc") and now it's saying that it can't find the table name. I followed the example [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).

Comment: OK I'll try that route and see what happens. For the record - stop yelling. I made it very clear this was my first time using this framework.

Answer (score 19):

I think problem is that you wrote native query in @Query, but didn't set `@Query("...", nativeQuery=true)`, because this annotation accepts by default queries in JPQL. Read about @Query usage [there](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added that line at the end but I'm still seeing that same error.

Comment: Could you plealse write method below @Query?

Comment: GlobalLog findByGuid(String guid);

Sorry - not exactly sure how to get a code block in a comment reply.

Comment: Maybe it depends on how you pass parameter to query. Try to change 'value' to ?1 in query statement, then it should use String which you pass to method

Comment: No bueno still. It's heavily focused on the "1" after my SELECT TOP. It's like it's taking the 1 and trying to use it as a name or something instead of the row number that I want. Unfortunately I don't know too much about SQL to know whether this is happening or not. Thanks for your replies tho!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your database platform does not support TOP

For Oracle you could use ROWNUM <=1

```
@Query("select * from 'table name' where 'column' like 'value' and message like 'value' order by 'column' desc ROWNUM <=1", nativeQuery = true)
```

For MySQL you could use LIMIT 1

```
@Query("select * from 'table name' where 'column' like 'value' and    message like 'value' order by 'column' desc LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Tried this too and it just doesn't care for anything I'm doing. Here is the new query:

    `code`@Query("select * from 'table name' where 'column' like 'value' and message like 'value' order by 'column' desc LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)

Also, here are the properties in my properties file (if it helps):

url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ip:host
username: username
password: password
driver: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

EDIT: Bleh..this damn reply formatting :(

Comment: Have you tried to run this query directly into database? The same error appears?

Comment: I have. I use HeidiSQL (at work) and the query returns 1 result which is what I'm expecting.